# I want to translate ROS Tutorials in Korean

Tags: ros, translation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a student in Korea and studying ROS.

I have been studying ROS with ROS Wiki in Korean.

But some tutorials are not translated, and other tutorials are written in 2013, 2012...

So I want to translate ROS tutorials in Korean, but I don't know how to translate them.

Please let me know how to translate them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311848/i-want-to-translate-ros-tutorials-in-korean/) by [Dovidy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38989/dovidy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, welcome to the ROS community and nice to hear you want to help translate wiki content.

Translating is not really that different from regular *editing*, and for that you first need an account. There are two steps:

1. register for an account [here](http://wiki.ros.org/action/newaccount/Documentation?action=newaccount)
2. request *write access* by commenting on [this github issue](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/258)

At this point you can access the wiki and edit pages.

To translate a tutorial (or any page really):

1. make a copy of the page and place it in the `ko` sub dir (use `Copy page` from the `More Actions` dropdown (on the right side of the page, under `Page`)
2. translate
3. save

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dovidy](https://answers.ros.org/users/38989/dovidy/) on 2019-01-06**:
Thanks for your kind reply!